# mysql workbench select and select into issue

Tags: mysql, select, select-into

not sure why this is baffling me.. strange that have the things I see for how to do this are showing as errors in the workbench..
so I want to select first into var and select out next.. then use the var to update.. but
it never works.. so I found you had to do the into thing.. and now that shows red x on it.. what is wrong with it ?

```
    use reunionfunfacts;
drop procedure if exists reunionfunfacts.getTrueFact;
DELIMITER //


CREATE PROCEDURE getTrueFact(in in_idperson int)

BEGIN
DECLARE _idtrue_fact    int;

select
    idtrue_fact into _idtrue_fact,
    fact_text
from 
    reunionfunfacts.true_fact
where 
    in_idperson = idperson and fact_in_use = 0 or fact_in_use is null
order by rand() limit 1;


update reunionfunfacts.true_fact set fact_in_use=1 where idtrue_fact=_idtrue_fact;
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. You can't use MySQL Workbench with SQL Server, nor SSMS with MySQL

Comment: Your title says "mysql workbench" but your tags say `sql-server`.

Comment: Are you trying to select one column into 2 variables? and can you rephrase 'so I want to select first into var and select out next'  what purpose does fact_text serve you don't appear to use it.

Comment: I'm not mixing sql and mysql.. its all mysql. I didnt try to add a tag for sql-server.. sorry.. So I want to select the idtrue_fact into a var and select out the fact_text. So the sp should just return the fact_text to my c# program and the sp should use the idtrue_fact to update the table.

Comment: You cannot do both in the same query a select into does not also return a result set. You may need 2 queries..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Columns so you have to add to INTO variables like this

But i don't know if TEXT is enough for your fact text

```
drop procedure if exists reunionfunfacts.getTrueFact;
DELIMITER //


CREATE PROCEDURE getTrueFact(in in_idperson int)

BEGIN
DECLARE _idtrue_fact    int;
DECLARE _fact_text    TEXT;

select
    idtrue_fact ,
    fact_text
    INTO _idtrue_fact, _fact_text
from 
    reunionfunfacts.true_fact
where 
    in_idperson = idperson and fact_in_use = 0 or fact_in_use is null
order by rand() limit 1;


update reunionfunfacts.true_fact set fact_in_use=1 where idtrue_fact=_fact_text;
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: so its all or nothing ? you cant select one out normal and select one into a var ?

Comment: as you can see i put both in variables, so use both or none that doesn't matter